# CSS how to apply :first-child and :last-child

Tags: html, css, addthis

I have a problem using CSS `:first-child` and `:last-child`.

I need add some space between tag `<a>` for the first tag I need only margin-bottom:5px and for the last tag 0px.

Here my code.. What I'm doing wrong here? Any other alternative? Thanks

```
.addthis_toolbox.atfixed
    {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 32px;
    }
    .addthis_toolbox:first-child
    {
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    .addthis_toolbox:last-child
    {
     margin-bottom:0px;
    }
```

---

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_32x32_style atfixed">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e55018a5d405a71"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly fixing what you provided, you need:

```
.addthis_toolbox a:first-child
{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.addthis_toolbox a:last-child
{
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

The problem with `.addthis_toolbox:first-child` is that it selects a `.addthis_toolbox` that is the first child of its parent. And that's not what you wanted.

---

I might be getting confused here, but if you're trying to add a gap between *every* `a`, use this to handle it:

```
.addthis_toolbox a + a {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

It's neater and has better browser support due to not using `:last-child`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a space between `.addthis_toolbox` and `:first-child`/`:last-child`

Otherwise, it'll only select `.addthis_toolbox` elements that are the first or last child of their parents.

`:first-child` is applied to the element, selecting *only* elements where the element *is* the `first-child` of its parent.

You can read more about how the pseudo-selectors work in the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child).